# Hexidecimal Matlab ouput in wrong format

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a double array in matlab whose elements are being output to a file in hexidecimal format. I want to output it with no decimal places and I can't seem to figure out how to do this when the value being output is a negative number. I've tried:

```
    >> A = ones(1,4);
    >> fid = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
    >> value = A(2);
    >> fid = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
    >> fprintf(fid,'%x\r\n', value);
    >> fprintf(fid,'%.0x\r\n', value);
    >> value = -value;
    >> fprintf(fid,'%.0x\r\n', value);
    >> fprintf(fid,'%0.0x\r\n', value);
    >> fprintf(fid,'%0.0x\r\n', value);
    >> fprintf(fid,'%1.0x\r\n', value);
    >> fprintf(fid,'%x\r\n', value);
```

And the output file looks like:

```
    1
    1
    -1e+000
    -1e+000
    -1e+000
    -1e+000
    -1.000000e+000
```

I really just want it to be able to print out '-1';

Sorry if this is obvious but its really hard to find this information as there are so many different formats.

Comment: I tried to answer, but misunderstood the question. Now why do you need to output `double` values in hexadecimal?

Comment: Well they are actually all integer values. I only want them to be integers but I'm pretty sure it is an array of doubles. Rounding would do fine if it worked, but it doesn't.

Comment: Have a look at [Two's Complement for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5485-twos-complement-for-matlab) in MATLAB File Exchange.

Comment: by definition, %x is an unsigned number (base 16). Hence the choke... What you're seeing isn't a base 16 representation, it's decimal. Try it for val = 12. In base 16, you should see `c`, whereas -val gives `-12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing `value = -value;` to `value = round(-value);`?

Alternatively, output absolute values only, but prepend '-' if the value is negative:

```
if value < 0, 
  fprintf('-%x', abs(value));
else
  fprintf('%x', abs(value));
end
```

Comment: If you only need to output one value at a time, put the code above into a wrapper function hexprintf(val). I don't think you're likely to find a better solution.